# MikTeX 2.9 internal Error - StringHandlerImpl.h

Tags: xetex, miktex, texlipse

i have a fresh and updated install of MikTeX 2.9 (64-Bit) installed on my Win10 maschine. I use it with eclipse neon (Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)) and the texlipse (1.5.0) plugin. I installed PDF4Eclipse 1.1.0.

**Edit:** Using TeXnicCenter with the same MikTeX Distribution works fine. So i think the problem is with eclipse or the texlipse plugin.

Settings for building are:

```
Output: pdf
builder: xelatex.exe
build parameter: -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials "%input"
```

Every time I want to build my latex project it fails. The console in eclipse shows:

```
running: D:\Programme\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials GenerateRP.tex 
xelatex.exe> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit)
xelatex.exe> entering extended mode
xelatex.exe> (GenerateRP.tex
xelatex.exe> LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
xelatex.exe> Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
xelatex.exe> (../sources/main.tex (../sources/template.tex
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
xelatex.exe> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size12.clo))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty   
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\switch.def)
xelatex.exe> *************************************
xelatex.exe> * Local config file bblopts.cfg used
xelatex.exe> *
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\babel-german\ngerman.ldf
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\babel-german\ngermanb.ldf
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\babel.def
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\switch.def)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\xebabel.def)))))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\xelatex\xetexconfig\geometry.cfg))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tools\array.sty))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\ltablex\ltablex.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fancybox\fancybox.sty
xelatex.exe> Style option: `fancybox' v1.4 <2010/05/15> (tvz)
xelatex.exe> ) (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def)))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\float\float.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tocbibind\tocbibind.sty
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> Package tocbibind Note: Using section or other style headings.
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> ) (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\colortbl\colortbl.sty))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\caption\ltcaption.sty))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\lm\t1lmr.fd))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\xltxtra\xltxtra.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\tuenc.def))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\realscripts\realscripts.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\metalogo\metalogo.sty))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\microtype\microtype-xetex.def)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.cfg))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\makecmds\makecmds.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex))))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\polyglossia\gloss-german.ldf)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\ulem\ulem.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty)(../sources/trennung.tex)
xelatex.exe>  (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty))
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\url\url.sty))
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\hyperref\hxetex.def
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\hyperref\puenc.def)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\stringenc.sty)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))) (GenerateRP.aux)
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd)
xelatex.exe> *geometry* detected driver: pdftex
xelatex.exe> *geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
xelatex.exe> * driver: pdftex
xelatex.exe> * paper: a4paper
xelatex.exe> * layout: <same size as paper>
xelatex.exe> * layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
xelatex.exe> * modes: 
xelatex.exe> * h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 441.01773pt, 85.35826pt)
xelatex.exe> * v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 702.78308pt, 71.13188pt)
xelatex.exe> * \paperwidth=597.50787pt
xelatex.exe> * \paperheight=845.04684pt
xelatex.exe> * \textwidth=441.01773pt
xelatex.exe> * \textheight=702.78308pt
xelatex.exe> * \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
xelatex.exe> * \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
xelatex.exe> * \topmargin=-38.1381pt
xelatex.exe> * \headheight=23.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \headsep=25.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \topskip=12.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \footskip=30.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \marginparwidth=35.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \marginparsep=10.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \columnsep=10.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \hoffset=0.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \voffset=0.0pt
xelatex.exe> * \mag=1000
xelatex.exe> * \@twocolumnfalse
xelatex.exe> * \@twosidefalse
xelatex.exe> * \@mparswitchfalse
xelatex.exe> * \@reversemarginfalse
xelatex.exe> * (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
xelatex.exe> (D:\Programme\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty)) (GenerateRP.out)
xelatex.exe>  (GenerateRP.out)
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> Sorry, but D:\Programme\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe did not succeed.
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe>   C:/Users/ppfuetzenreuter/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/xelatex.log
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

The mentioned log file says:

```
ERROR xelatex.core - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
ERROR xelatex.core - Data: 
ERROR xelatex.core - Source: libraries\miktex\texandfriends\include\miktex\texandfriends\StringHandlerImpl.h:47
FATAL xelatex - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
FATAL xelatex - Info: 
FATAL xelatex - Source: libraries\miktex\texandfriends\include\miktex\texandfriends\StringHandlerImpl.h
FATAL xelatex - Line: 47
INFO  xelatex - finishing with exit code 1
INFO  xelatex - starting with command line: D:\Programme\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials template.tex
INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
INFO  xelatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
INFO  xelatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:** reproduced the problem with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \section{Title}
    \subsection{Subtitle}
        Plain text.
    \subsection{Another subtitle}
        More plain text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first step is to get a smaller example. That means compile on the command line and not eclipse and remove all packages that are not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Running the build in console generates exactly the same output as in the eclipse console. In my opinion all included packages are needed. I added the part with the inclusions in my post, maybe you can tell me which packages i should remove.

Comment: I have no idea which package you should remove. Try out a small hello world document. If it compiles that the problem is with one of the packages and you will have to find out which. If it doesn't compile then obviously none of your packages are relevant to debug the issue.

Comment: I will try what you mentioned using eclipse. Maybe its not compatible with one of the packages. I also edited my question.

Comment: Sorry but why do you use eclipse? That's a tool for software developers but you seem to have absolutly no clue how to analyse a software problem.

Comment: well thats kind of embarrassing for me... cause I actually am software developer and eclipse is my ide. the document i want to build is splitted in many parts and under version control. I also use DebugView to trace the MikTex build process. But sometimes the most simple ideas are the best... the whole time i was focused on miktex.

Comment: Well I hope you are not trying to debug this with your original document. When I get such problems the first thing I do is to create a copy in a local test folder so that I can play around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After comparing the build processes of TeXnicCenter and eclipse changing the build parameters was the solution:

simply change:

```
-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials "%input"
```

to:

```
-interaction=nonstopmode %input
```

Comment: Only `--src-specials` must be removed. `-synctex=1` and the quotes around `%input` are ok. I had the exact same error and only had to remove `--src-specials`.
There’s btw a 2.0.0 version since a few days https://github.com/eclipse/texlipse/ (project link is there). Eclipse picked the project up a few months ago :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After installing TeXlipse 2.0.0 it worked the way you descriped. With version 1.5.0 of the plugin removing only `--src-specials` did not work for me.

Comment: fyi: I reported the bug in with XeLaTex and `--src-specials` in 2017 (https://github.com/eclipse/texlipse/issues/47) and it has been fixed mid 2018 with commit https://github.com/eclipse/texlipse/commit/98fe7b78d7b5f1bbcd4f70d1155d72432321e582